# Mantaflow simulations causing strange diamond artefacts

Tags: fluid-simulation

I've create a fluid simulation with mantaflow and am rendering the FLIP particles themselves (no mesh). The simulation looks great (with a resolution of 96) but when it becomes quite turbulent there are strange "diamond shaped" artefacts appearing and disappearing sporadically.

You can see it here:

[image]

And it's very noticeable in video (in the center where the two fluids meet):

[image]

Is there a way to get rid or reduce these artefacts?

Comment: have you tried changing the resolution?

Comment: try having resolution values like 32, 64, 128,  or 256

Comment: @Jonas I tried different resolutions yes.

Comment: @Rakeshchoudhary Mh, I had 96 as a resolution. You think that this could be the issue?

Comment: Please attach blend to your Q via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com Thank you

Comment: I tried with 128 but the diamonds were just a bit smaller.

Comment: Any problem post the blend I asked for? A you can see your red sim in fine, means yellow setup produce it. We don't know what whole setup is used, means - it is hard to help when we don't know what setup you use :)

Comment: @vklidu the blender file is really big, because it contains high-res models and the simulation data is ~5GB. The Red part generates the exact same diamond artefacts, it's just not as visible. I have 6 simulations in total, with the exact same problem.

Comment: @enyo I haven't seen this artefact before, and from silent here maybe also others don't know how to reproduce these diamonds, means - they can't look for different setup if works or not. (also it can be something that just sim works like this and there is not a fix at the moment). Also what blender version was used? BTW I don't think you have to share baked and meshed sim. Keep just domain and flow object (or other elements used in sim), or append them into a new blend and share, they should be just a few kB.